# I get an error when i upload this code into unity

Tags: c#, collision

I dont know what is wrong with this code please help me this is the error:
Assets\playerColision.cs(4,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PlayerMovement' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using UnityEngine;
public class playerColision : MonoBehaviour{
    public PlayerMovement movement;

   void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
   {
       if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle"){
      
       }

   }
}
```

And the other code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class playerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
public float forwardForce = 2000f;
public float sidewaysForce = 500f;

    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
     rb.AddForce(forwardForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
                if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
     rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# is case sensitive. Your class is named `playerMovement` but your variable `PlayerMovement`. This must be equal.

Comment: Thank you but i still get one more error : OnGUIDepth changed: was 0 is 1. Event type was 0